Grounding isolated electrical circuit from a floating source (EV V2L)
UPDATE: The car is a Hyundai Ioniq 6 EV. The V2L function is provided by either a dongle that plugs into the cats J1772 charging port or (in the case of my trim level, "Limited") by a 5-15 outlet under the back seat. In my case, the dongle is a 3rd-party model, not sold by Hyundai; however, I have confirmed the observations with the built-in outlet under the back seat.
I have, since the original post, made the following observations:
1. The 5-15 ground slot is indeed connected to chassis ground.
2. However, the ground slot is not bonded to either hot/neutral slot of the outlet (observed as "open ground" on an outlet tester). The inverter outlet is isolated.
3. I have been unable to find that the outlet provides GFCI protection. (There is no mention in the car's owner manual and, due to the unbonded ground, I am unable to test it.)
Therefore, I have decided that the proper approach is as follows:
1. Ground the car's cassis to a proper earth ground, using a large-gauge wire from a clip attached to the car's chassis to, in my case, what I know to be an all-copper water main coming up from the ground nearby (if this weren't available, I'd use a proper ground rod). This is per @gredhill 's answer about OSHA regulations on vehicle-mounted generators.
2. Add an in-line GFCI, such as the Huskey in-line GFCI to the extension cord.
I own an electric vehicle which includes the capability of vehicle-to-load (through a dongle) which turns the whole vehicle effectively into a battery pack/inverter providing a NEMA 5-15 120 volt 15 amp outlet. Even though the outlet provides a ground pin, it is, of course, only grounded to the car’s chassis.
I’m thinking that in case of a utility power outage where I would run an extension cord from the car to a few lights/appliances (isolated from the house electrical), that having the circuit floating is not a good idea. Is there any reason not to connect (only) this ground to the house electrical ground?
I’m envisioning building a cord with two 5-15 plugs but only the ground pins connected. Similar to a so-called suicide cord, except not dangerous because neither the hot nor neutral are connected. (The cord would be well labeled, of course.) The ends of this cable would be plugged into a multi-way splitter on the powered extension cord and into a household outlet.
Would it help if I used ground-only plugs (where the hot/ neutral prongs are plastic)?
Is there any reason, legal or otherwise not to do this?

<devil's advocate> Some appliances might be grounded independently, e.g. a freezer through the icemaker water supply line. </devil's advocate>

Speaking purely about the technique, I did once make a cord like that to experiment with noise shielding in crappy old hummy audio equipment.  At the wall end you don't need plastic pins.  Just tighten or remove the screws on the two power pins so they don't work loose and fall.   And at the equipment end I just had a bare wire to fool around with.

Not my area, but I'd have expected the "dongle" to have some provision for grounding at the car.   Can you tell us more about the vehicle and its dongle?  Manufacturer, etc.  Is the Dongle from the car manufacturer or a third party ?

As your use does not appear to be work-related in any way OSHA rules do not necessarily apply; however, they might provide some insight you'd appreciate.
OSHA has rules regarding the grounding of portable- and vehicle-mounted generators. (OSHA Fact Sheet Grounding Requirements for Portable Generators) In my mind the EV vehicle-to-load scenario looks quite comparable to a vehicle-mounted fuel-driven electric generator.
In a nutshell that fact sheet says that when the load is mounted on the generator, or is cord-and-plug connected to outlets on the generator, then the frame of the generator "need not be grounded and the frame may serve as the ground." If the full conditions described in the fact sheet do not exist (and when the OSHA rules apply..), then a grounding electrode system is required. If the generator is providing power to a structure then the grounding electrode system is required.
You certainly could choose to connect the grounding. A male-male ground-only cord isn't my favorite way of doing the job though! The 5-15 plug on the vehicle end is fine but for the other end I'd rather see an alligator clip (to attach directly to the ground rod outside) or some other non-NEMA, single-pole connector. Perhaps a banana plug, a PowerPole connector, or something along those lines. Even a ring terminal which you'd attach to a screw or stud that's on the building grounding system would be great.
The whole discussion assumes that neutral and ground in the EV inverter are bonded together so that a fault to ground is a fault to neutral, which trips a protective device. Note that if you were to connect the EV inverter to the building via a transfer switch you'd need to arrange things to avoid having two ground-neutral bonds -- but that's not a scenario you asked about here.

The OSHA document is interesting!   When an isolated portable generator correctly uses its frame as the ground reference, its instructions tell you how to stake it to ground if you want but not when.   Lightning:  Good reason I guess, if your portable generator is outside in a storm.   EMI: If you need EMI protection on generator you must be thinking and planning on another level.  You're not using a generator from Harbor Freight or a Prius to power your mobile hospital.

FWIW: NEC 250.34 echoes the OSHA advice re: vehicle-mounted generators.  Also, 4mm banana plugs fit into NEMA 5-15 ground holes fairly well IME

Briefly: Do not do it.   Bonding your EV/extension-cord system, isolated from your home, to ground in the way you describe provides no added protection from anything and creates distraction and extra trip hazards during times of distress.   Keep it simple.   An EV outlet with a suitable extension cord is fine to directly power some critical appliances.  Suitable cords are 3-pin, as short as possible and suitable gauge for the load.
In more detail: What faults are you protecting yourself from?

Appliance chassis contact with live - in this case the ground wire in the extension cord, and your vehicle's circuit breaker will do what's needed. The short circuit between hot and your vehicle chassis (the actual "ground" reference) will blow the breaker.
Direct human contact with live - illustratively, sticking your finger in the socket.  In this case your vehicle probably has GFCI protection on its outlet, and that will protect you from this class of fault.  The "G" in GFCI is a misdirection, the actual earth has nothing to do with it.  RTFM!  If your vehicle does not provide GFCI, just buy a GFCI widget for your extension cord.  They are on the same shelf at the store.
Lightning - I suppose, If your vehicle is struck by lightning and your body happens to provide a better ground path than the tires right at that moment, a well-planned and well-executed grounding system could help.  But your 1-pin cord plugged in to the nearest wall outlet is neither of those.  In fact, it probably makes things a LOT worse, by connecting your isolated system to one that is far more likely to get involved in a lightning strike.

If you're going to clamp the reference (chassis) to ground you need to   know what faults you're mitigating, how it's going to work, and then how to best execute it, which is unlikely to be just connecting to the nearest wall outlet ground pin.

Consider an AC generator isolated from Earth, followed by a RCD breaker, then a load. A human touches the Live wire. The human has feet on the ground, so he's Earthed.

Current can only flow in a complete closed circuit.
In this case there is no fully closed circuit, so no current flows. The RCD detects no current, so it does not trip.
On the plus side, it means you can touch items connected to the Live wire without getting zapped. The drawback is, if one of your devices is defective, wet, or has an internal short from Live to chassis, making it a death trap... still, no closed circuit, no current, RCD will not trip, and no one is aware there is a fault waiting to zap someone.
This is why the usual scheme is this one, with Neutral tied to Earth somewhere before the RCD (where depends on country, in France it's at the utility transformer):

In this case there is a closed circuit through Live, the human touching it, Earth, back to the generator through Earth, Neutral, then Live. The human touching Live is part of this circuit, and he definitely gets zapped for a couple milliseconds, before the RCD trips.
With this type of installation, contrary to the previous one, it is not safe to touch Live. But if there is a faulty device waiting to kill you with Live on the chassis, and the chassis is Earthed, the RCD will trip and alert you of the situation before you touch it and get zapped. Much better.
If there is no RCD, then... natural selection will follow its course.
Before RCDs, this scheme was used with fuses. A hard short from Live to Earth in a faulty device would allow enough current to flow to blow the fuse, working kinda like a RCD, which is good... but there is a wide range of fault currents between "enough to kill you" (30mA) and "enough to blow a fuse" (maybe 10-16A).
Besides, never count on inverters to have enough juice to blow a fuse in case of a hard short circuit. Most likely the inverter will shut down to save itself much faster than the fuse can blow.
Basically, this is mostly about setting up the circuit so the RCD will trip when it should. Preferably right when a fault occurs and before it zaps someone. Worst case, it should trip when someone get zapped.
Example:
My photovoltaic inverter has a backup output which is normally connected to the grid via internal relays. Grid Neutral is tied to Earth at the power station, this passes through the inverter, so the backup output's Neutral is also tied to Earth. So the RCD on the backup output works properly.
In case of blackout, internal relays disconnect the backup output from the now dead grid, and the inverter produces power. Being disconnected from the grid, the backup output's Neutral is no longer tied to Earth. Thus, another internal relay connects the backup output Neutral to Earth. This ensures the RCD on the output of the inverter still will work properly.
Now the question you're asking is different: you're talking about earthing the car's chassis, and I'm talking about earthing Neutral.
Obviously, the car should have no problem with Earthing the chassis, as it occurs every time the tyres get wet, or it gets lifted at the garage, every time you touch it, plug it to charge it, etc.
But for the safety aspect, it's not possible to answer this question without more documentation about the car.
Specifically, I have no idea if the car ties its output Neutral to its chassis internally.
Note conditionals:
If it does tie Neutral to Chassis, then it implies a TT Earthing scheme (the second one described above) was intended by the manufacturer, and Earthing the chassis could be safe for the car and provide a safety benefit. RCD must be used, Earthing the car's chassis (and Neutral) will cause it to trip when it should. In this case I wouldn't be surprised if the car had an onboard RCD on the output, most likely a fancy type B (AC-DC-HF) mandated in such cases, rated for DC fault current, etc. In this case, you could Earth the car using the charging plug, assuming its Earth pin is connected to its chassis. Should be more elegant than a suicide cord with two male prongs and a "just kidding this is safe" sticker on it.
If it does not tie Neutral to chassis:
Then it implies an Earthing scheme as the first case described above. Earthing the car's chassis will provide no safety benefit, as it will not close the circuit and trip the RCD in case of fault. Earthing the car's chassis should not be dangerous as your car should... probably... not be designed to kill you if you use the AC V2L output while the car is plugged into the charger and thus Earthed.
Earthing the Neutral may or may not destroy some hardware or cause a dangerous situation. Impossible to tell without more documentation, but please consider:
Any system with high voltage DC, and especially high voltage high power battery (400V DC, hundreds of amps) deserves respect. If the car's inverter is not isolated from the battery and in case of a fault in the car's inverter, worst case scenario would be 400V DC on the output. Now HV DC between two wires isolated from Earth is already way more dangerous than AC, it will incinerate any breakers or RCDs intended for AC in just a few seconds because DC arcs do not self-extinguish... But if Neutral is Earthed and this occurs, if the inverter fails now you have HV DC between the wires and Earth: the best combo available for electrocution and fire at the same time (during a blackout).

This  is an interesting and well-thought-out answer! However, respectfully, I had a hard time finding the "what should OP do" part. Could you please put in a short highlighted summary regarding OP's ground the car idea?

The point is... the actual answer depends on the car's implementation, which I don't know about, so I have no idea what OP should do in his specific case (besides read the car's documentation). Without more information, "do nothing" would probably be the most reasonable.

One of the main purposes of a ground wire is so that if you have a fault in equipment that the circuit would be completed by hot -> ground (instead of hot -> neutral) very quickly and effectively so that the breaker will trip.
If you route ground from the device to the building ground then the electricity will have an extremely hard time getting back to the source - your car's electrical system. Which means that the breaker would not trip quickly, if at all. If the device in question has a grounded metal case then that case would be electrically hot, which would be very dangerous.
GFCI can alleviate this problem quite a bit, but there is no guarantee (unless handled in the car, which it might be) that everything connected will be GFCI protected.
So no, this is very much NOT a good idea.

The vehicle outlet ground pin should provide a short circuit path that will protect the appliance chassis and fault the circuit breaker if needed.   Bonding the appliance to ground would make this no worse.   You're right it would not provide a good ground path, but THAT isn't what makes this a bad idea.
